# MW3 Prestige Unlock One Item

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When I use a Prestige Token to Unlock Gear, what happens?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37095/when-i-use-a-prestige-token-to-unlock-gear-what-happens)

With the prestige shop, the option to unlock one item, is that permanently through that prestige round?  Or through all future prestige rounds?  Is it a choice of any gun, equipment, one or all of the above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, that item is permanently unlocked at all future prestige levels. However, the weapon level will reset.

You have a choice of guns, lethal and tactical equipment, and perks.